# Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter convertView

Tags: android, kotlin, adaptor

I got this error just after converted the adapter code to Kotlin:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter convertView
    at ...MyAdapter.getView(Unknown Source:35)
    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2366)
```

The error fires when inflating the row:

```
class LegalAdapter internal constructor(private val activity: Activity, private val list: ArrayList<Item>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {

    val layoutInflater = activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    val row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.legal_list_item, parent, false) //exception is throw here
```

Apparently, some parameter that shouldn't be null is null, and kotlin check it. Problem is i can't even debug the new kotlin code.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `getView()` method is a part of the `Adapter` interface, and is defined in Java. [Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)). The important part is this note about the `convertView` parameter:

> **View**: The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using.

This means that it's quite valid for the framework to pass `null` values for `convertView` to this method (meaning that you need to create a new view and return that, rather than recycling an old view).

In turn, this means that the Kotlin definition of `convertView` must be of type `View?`, not just `View`. So change your function signature to this:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View
```

Comment: The signature auto generated by the tool. But yes, it was precisely that. Also, it solved the problem with the debugger. Now it stops again on a breakpoint inside the method.

Comment: Wow! I would have cried for hours trying to figure this thing out.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a magic, Thank you. This happens we we convert a Java file into Kotlin. If you are using Kotlin when you are creating this BaseAdapter, then you won't have to do check this import signature.

Answer (score 18):

Make `convertView` nullable:

```
convertView: View?
```

I'm not sure why the line number is wrong, but the stacktrace tells you where to look in the error message.

Answer (score 8):

Change your convertView in getView from non-null to nullable

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {
```

to

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
```

Answer (score 0):

All correct solutions are already posted above. Just one more with some code and ViewBinding:

```
class SpinnerAdapter(
      context: Context,
      private val items: List<YourModel>
) : BaseAdapter() {

private var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

override fun getView(i: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
    return if (convertView != null) {
        convertView
    } else {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner, null)
        val binding = ItemSpinnerBinding.bind(view)
        val item = items[i]
        binding.name.text = item.name
        view
    }
}

//more overridde methods
}
```

Where my R.layout.item_spinner has a TextView with an Id called "name".